# how to get 32FC1 from realsense d435 depth topic

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, realsense

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, I want to get sensor_msgs/Imagic from /camera/depth/image_rect_raw with 32FC1, I have changed the rs_rgbd.launch, set align_depth = false. There are some new topics of sw_registered, but on them the image_encodings is still 16UC1.So where is my fault?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302639/how-to-get-32fc1-from-realsense-d435-depth-topic/) by [yueweiliang](https://answers.ros.org/users/28206/yueweiliang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2018-09-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the script given the ROS package available below. It converts the depth encoding **16UC1** to **32FC1**.

https://github.com/tim-fan/realsense_spencer_adaptor

---

Originally posted by [kivrakh](https://answers.ros.org/users/31606/kivrakh/) with karma: 16 on 2019-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0